# my sql field sum using another field to differentiate and then sort it

Tags: mysql, select, count, sum

I would like to ask something about query using mysql

I have this table called video_stat, and here's the field

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `video_stat` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `video_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `member_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `counter` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `daydate` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `monthdate` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `epochtime` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

the 'counter' field will be updated per day

and my question is that, I would like to sort this field, by sum-ing the counter as total per video_id and then sort them by total per video_id to then display the list on a popular video page. how can I do that?

I thought that it would work using this query:

```
SELECT SUM( counter ) AS total_viewed, member_id, video_id
FROM member_video_stat
```

but it will only sums up everything on the counter field and return a single row since the SUM(counter) part did not count for each and particular video_id

illustration:

current table

```
+--------------+-----------+---------+
| id| video_id | member_id | counter | 
+---+----------+-----------+---------+
| 4 |      6   |       2   |       1 |
| 5 |      9   |       6   |       1 |
| 6 |      12  |       2   |       1 |
| 7 |      6   |       2   |       1 |
| 8 |      12  |       2   |       1 |
+--------------+-----------+---------+
```

to something like

```
    +----------+-----------+---------+
    | video_id | member_id | total   |
    +----------+-----------+---------+
    |      6   |       2   |       2 |
    |      9   |       6   |       1 |
    |      12  |       2   |       2 |
    +----------+-----------+---------+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give this a try

```
SELECT SUM(counter) AS total_viewed, member_id, video_id
FROM member_video_stat
GROUP BY video_id
ORDER BY total_viewed DESC
```

Hoa

Comment: wow that was fast...i was still editing...this works like a charm, thanks a lot

Comment: Note: if there is a video_id with more than one member_id, you will end up with *one* row for that video_id in your result set, giving you the correct total and a member_id that is (more or less) randomly picked from the member_ids associated with that video_id.